# Hide a partially visible line in a text view (Android)?

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with fixed height that contains text downloaded from a server. Sometimes the text is more than the view can wrap and it is cutting the extra text. The problem is that the last line the view can show is only partially visible which is kind of ugly.

Is there a way not to show a line if it is only partially visible?
android:maxLines wont help, because my layout has two textviews with different font sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `textview` scrollable. Add these lines :

```
android:maxLines = 'int'  // put any integer value.
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:ellipsize`

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
android:elegantTextHeight="true"
```